# Install MySQL in fedora

Tags: mysql, fedora

I am installing mysql and mysql-server in fedora.What I did was:

`su` (to change to root)

`yum install mysql mysql-server`

`chkconfig --levels 235 mysqld on`

and when I try to start `mysqld` using `/etc/init.d/mysqld start`, it gives me an error saying `No such a file or directory`.

By using `whereis mysql` I got the following result:

```
$whereis mysql
mysql: /usr/bin/mysql /usr/lib/mysql /usr/share/mysql /usr/share/man/man1/mysql.1.gz
```

Can some one help me find where I installed mysql and how I can start it? Thank you

Comment: Sounds like a question for superuser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try starting MySQL by using `service mysqld start` instead.